# Compilation Error: "higher version than referenced assembly "

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I got error on my view page so I updated my visual studio to mvc4, though I am working on mvc3. I 1st updated using NuGet but it don't works so, I updated through standalone MVC4. so it worked. But when I tried to run MVC3 project it gives me following Error:

> CS1705: Assembly 'MVC3Project, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher
>   version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the web.config file in the Views folder there is the host element under system.web.webPages.razor

This should be as follows for an MVC3 project:

```
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

While for MVC4 it is:

```
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

You also need to check the pages element is as follows for MVC3

```
<pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
```

and the sectionGroup element:

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
```

In the main web.config in the root directory of the project you need to make sure that the assemblies element is as follows:

```
<assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
```

There are more changes to make - best bet is to look at the web.config files for an MVC3 project and an MVC4 project and remove the stuff that shouldn't be there in yours.

Comment: Somewhere you have a defintion that specifies the v4 Assembly as the application expects it, but you have the v3 assembly referenced (as it should be for a MVC3 project).

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with a later version of MVC.  After I updated all my packages through Nugget, the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization

Answer (score 0):

The worked solution for me i deleted the reference in project which gives error.

Reinstall that again with right click project -> add references --> search the name of Assembly then add that again.

for this question you have to delete System.Web.Mvc under first project references and click project -> add references --> Search  System.Web.Mvc  (you will see that is 4.0.0.0 now) install it.

Answer (score -1):

you can download System.Web.Mvc.dll with version that you are looking for then :

Reference -> add ->browse and select ur file.

this solution worked for me !!

Good luck