# I added a cshtml file and then got 22 assembly uses higher version errors. What went wrong and how do I fix?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, .net-assembly

I'm working on an MVC Web application and encountered a problem:

I added a cshtml file and out of nowhere 22 errors popped up in test case projects saying "MVC Web Application" uses a higher version than referenced assembly. When I visit the web application home page I get the error, even though there are no build errors on the Web Application itself, only test case projects.

This has happened before so I don't feel comfortable just "downgrading" everything since I don't know what it was like before and I'm afraid that every time I add a cshtml file I will need to commit everything to source control or risk losing it all. Could you please help? Is there any other information I could provide to help?

Comment: what .net framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using .Net 4.5

Comment: What I don't get about it especially, is the error I get when I search through the entire document is the assembly version in .csproj is 5.2.3, and in other places web configs I see v 4.0.0. Why did csproj update and why didn't the web.configs update? is there a "generic "4.0.0 and above" that I can stick in there?

Comment: And as well, what is dependent assembly "old version" for if the solution doesn't actually look at any old versions?

Comment: potential solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850643/compilation-error-higher-version-than-referenced-assembly

Comment: I ended up reverting. My boss doesn't want our keys in source control so I had a bit of trouble reverting because of the web config, which is making me a bigger fan of keeping an appsettings and connectionstrings file separate. Anyway, turns out I added "MVC 5 View with Razor" on an MVC4 project. It's frustrating because a similar error happens when I try to package another solution into a nuget package and download it to this solution... but for now I don't have as much time to look into it. I'll look at this answer and see if that helps with the NuGet. Thanks!